# Raspberry Pi keys are switched?

Tags: keyboard

I have a new Raspberry Pi, when I try to type double quotes by using shift and the single quote buttons on the keyboard, I get an @ symbol. When I do shift + 2, I get the double quotes. A few different keys are like this. How do I change this back to normal keyboard orientation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

run `sudo raspi-config` and setup your Locale and Keyboard. These are located under `Internationalisation Options`

Comment: Thanks, this worked well. 
    `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

brought me directly to the keyboard config.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I changed the locale from en_GB.UTF-8 to en_US.UTF-8 and reselected the Dell keyboard, but @ and quote are still swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Quote and @ get swapped if you're using a US keyboard with your locale set to UK. To fix: (FIXME why doesn't stackexchange support code in numbered lists?)

ONE. Update raspi-config (I'm not sure if this step is really necessary)

TWO. Enable US locale. `raspi-config` does *not* do this ([details](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33361/reconfigure-locale-failed))

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
update-locale en_US.UTF-8
```

THREE. Go into `raspi-config` option 4 (Localization Options) -> Change Keyboard Layout

- select your keyboard
- If "English (US)" is not shown (probably not -- that was the issue) go find it in Other, and select it. This brings you back to the main keyboard layout menu, where now "English (US)" is available.
- Finally, select "English (US)" again in the main keyboard layout menu.
- Select "OK" for the remaining options.