# reconfigure locale failed

Tags: debian, pi-2, locale

I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` via SSH.

[image]

After selecting <kbd><Ok></kbd> I have the error message below

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_CTYPE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_CTYPE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "C"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_CTYPE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "C"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

How should I proceed to set `en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply start

```
sudo raspi-config
```

[image]

and select <kbd>4 Internationalisation Options         Set up language and regional settings to match your location</kbd>

- To remove the error message select <kbd>de_DE.UTF-8</kbd>
- To select the default locale, in my case `en_GB.UTF-8`, select <kbd>en_GB.UTF-8</kbd>

Comment: No, selecting `de.DE.UTF-8` and then another locale does not fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
$ export LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8
$ export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
$ export LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
$ sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
$ sudo update-locale de_DE.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the locale file manually

```
$ nano /etc/default/locale
```

Change the original file from

```
File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

To this which local you want, for example:

```
#File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then reboot to apply the changes